# I get an error in my code

Tags: sql, c#-4.0, sql-server-express

I got an error

> Incorrect syntax near '.'. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Threading;

namespace Cloths_Inventory
{
    public partial class frmBackup : Form
    {
        //DataTable dtServers = SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers(true);
        //private static Server srvr;
        //private string DBpath = Application.StartupPath;

        public frmBackup()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool bBackUpStatus = true;
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

            if (Directory.Exists(@"D:\SQLBackup"))
            {
                if (File.Exists(@"D:\SQLBackup\wcBackUp1.bak"))
                {
                    if (MessageBox.Show(@"Do you want to replace it?", "Back", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        File.Delete(@"D:\SQLBackup\wcBackUp1.bak");
                    }
                    else
                        bBackUpStatus = false;
                }
            }
            else
                Directory.CreateDirectory(@"D:\SQLBackup");

            if (bBackUpStatus)
            {
                //Connect to DB
                SqlConnection connect;
                string con = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Garment.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Asynchronous Processing= True ;User Instance=True";

                connect = new SqlConnection(con);
                connect.Open();

                //Execute SQL---------------
                SqlCommand command;
                command = new SqlCommand(@"backup database Garment.mdf to disk ='E:Garment.bak' with init,stats=10", connect);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                //--------------

                connect.Close();

                MessageBox.Show("The support of the database was successfully performed", "Back", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to have any SQL queries with a CTE.

Comment: i want just only backup my application database and i used this code if u have any suggestion then plzzz give me

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the `AttachDbFileName=` approach and then use a server-based command like `backup database`....

If you want to back up your SQL Server database, it has to be attached to the **server**, and you need to connect to the server and issue that command:

```
// Connect to "master" database
string con = @"server=.\SQLEXPRESS;database=master;Integrated Security=True;";

SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(con);

SqlCommand ommand = new SqlCommand(@"backup database Garment to disk = N'E:\Garment.bak' with init,stats=10", connect);

connect.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connect.Close();
```

Comment: @user3925057: well then either give your current user that's running the code access to your SQL Server, or specify another user in the connection string that has access to the server ...

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a backslash E:Garment.bak should be E:\Garment.bak

```
command = new SqlCommand(@"backup database Garment.mdf to disk ='E:\Garment.bak' with init,stats=10", connect);
```